# Migration:Reference method is not found in subject class

Tags: php, laravel-5, migration

```
>  Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
>  $table->string('email')**->index();**
>  $table->string('token');
>  $table->timestamp('created_at')**->nullable();**
```

In migration file php storm is saying that the

> **Method 'index' not found in
>   Illuminate\Support\Fluent** and
>   **Referenced method is not found in subject clas.**

In any migration fail i can't chain like:

```
 Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {           
       $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');        
       $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended behaviour as `index()` is defined in [`Blueprint`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_index) - not in `Fluent`.

Change your code to the following:

```
// Create column
$table->string('email');

// Create the index
$table->index('email');

// Or, to create multiple indexes:
$table->index(['email', 'other_column']);
```

You can read more on creating indexes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-indexes).

Comment: $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); when i use references() same references not found in..

Comment: @savamilin Where are you getting this error? I suspect it's just your IDE complaining. Try running the migration, as this should work.

Comment: @savamilin And in the future please create separate questions for your issues.

Comment: ok thanks for advice i will separate questions. Yes in IDE PHPSTORM.When i run migrate he works.but i don't know if  method works becouse of yellow error that is on method, and it shows me 

    Method 'index'  not found in Illuminate\Support\Fluent and Referenced method is not found in subject clas.
or references on second question.